# how to update the text area using excel vba and selenium for intake forms or webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have coded the below program to update a text box with a value 'Test Data' not sure why it is not working can you please help me on this

Getting error in webdriver exception

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:209 in check_response
raise exception_class(value)

WebDriverException

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://formsbuilder-prod.aps.aw015.c.com/ui/portal/index.html?action=submit&form=R1JQLTJZRjlZLTlEeTNifEZSTS1IOWI0Ni1TUGNEVA")
driver.find_element("textbox")
```

Please include any detailed information for the new/update to the below:

1. Requester First/Last Name:
2. Requester Corp Id(W#):
3. Client Name:
4. Plan#(s):
5. Clone:
6. Detailed description of required change:

have to include the 'Test Data' within the textarea shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to grab the textbox, but don't put it in a variable or ask it to place text in the box. Try the following:

```py
textbox = driver.find_element("textbox")
textbox.clear()
textbox.sendkeys("some text")
```

Also the link that's in there doesn't seem to lead to anything.

Comment: Thanks Brock Brown.  Here is the textbox html. <input type="text" class="choices__input choices__input--cloned" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-label="false" placeholder="Type to search"> i have added your code not able to see thetext box updated.